# What is the "in" in the case statement?

Tags: shell, case

In a `case` statement like this:

```
case $foo in
        bar)
            echo "the value of foo is bar"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "the value of foo is not bar"
            ;;
esac
```

why is there an `in` after `case $foo`?  Wouldn't a syntax that dispensed with it be just as good or better?  What does it *mean?*

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It's just required by the syntax. And yes, there are an infinite number of possible syntaxes which could dispense with, but none of them is the syntax of the shell language.

Answer (score 1):

It's required by the syntax.

Semantically it introduces a set of one or more globs (expressions) for the `case` statement, against each of which the case variable is compared.

Note that you should be quoting `$foo` when you use it, i.e.

```
case "$foo" in ... esac
```

Comment: but why is the syntax like that, why isn't the in dispensed with?

Comment: Why is a circle round? Because it is.

Comment: surely whoever invented the language had a reason for making that choice, and surely there are many who can make an educated guess as to what that reason was

Comment: "case item in { value, value, value }" is more readable perhaps than "case item { value, value, value }"?

Comment: That's just happens to be a case where quoting the expansion is actually not needed.

Comment: Also, it (kinda) follows the same pattern as the `for` loop: `for var in list; do ...; done`. So that's `case $var in (case1) ... ;; (case2) ... ;; (case3) ... ;; esac`.

Comment: No, you should not be quoting in that case. Quoting it makes no difference.

Comment: @mosvy (and @kusalananda) rather than explaining the rules of double-quoting it's easier and more consistent to say "_always double-quote (unless you really know why you shouldn't)_".